# GraphicsMagick text issues

Tags: text, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to either add text to an existing image using GM, or as a last resort create a new image with text that I can then composite with the original image.  For some reason, I cannot seem to getting working...

I'm using GM 1.3.21 Q8 on Windows.

I found that this generates an white image with black text, but neither the gravity nor pointsize is making a difference.

`gm convert -background white -size 1480x50 -fill black -font Arial -pointsize 8 -gravity Center label:"Center this text" label.jpg`

I can't get anything to happen, ever with the `-draw text` command.  The sample in the GM help doesn't actually do anything.

At this point, I'm a little lost, and can't seem to locate an on-line resource that helps me out.  There is a great page for IM (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/), is there a similar one for GM?  Or am I attempting this all wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Along these lines:

```
gm convert -size 400x100 xc:yellow -fill black -pointsize 72 -gravity Center -draw 'text 0,0 "some text"' image.png
```

[image]

Comment: ok... I get the error: gm convert: Non-conforming drawing primitive definition (text) [No such file or directory].

Comment: Oh, you are on Windows. You probably have to do something mad like change the single quotes to double quotes. And maybe change the double quotes to single ones.

Comment: Yea... just playing with it, and this seams to be a magic combination that works.  (Had to add font too): gm convert -size 1480x50 xc:white -font Arial -fill black -pointsize 25 -gravity West -draw "text 25,0 'This is some text'" image.jpg

Comment: Excellent! Glad you are on the right track now. Good luck!